# htaccess port forwarding URLs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, portforwarding

I am looking to setup 2 .htaccess re-writes, but am not sure what they would actually look like:

```
http://www.mysite.com -> http://www.myothersite.com:880
```

and

```
https://www.mysite.com -> https://www.myothersite.com:4443
```

Just to deal with port-forwarding issues...

Here is what I am currently trying:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cloud\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.no-ip.org:880%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cloud\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ https://mysite.no-ip.org:4443%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/joomla" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ http://www.myothersite.com:880%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myothersite.com:4443%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot. Suppose I wanted to have this only apply to cloud.mysite.com woudl the only thing that would change above would be the "www" -> "cloud" ? And all other www access to my site would not be affected?

Comment: Yes just replace `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]` with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cloud\.mysite\.com$ [NC]`

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess is enabled. If yes then post your latest .htaccess in your question and provide some details like for what URL its not working.

Comment: Thanks for your .htaccess but for what URLs above rules are not working?

Comment: Neither of the cloud URLs are working. The URLs are not getting re-written. They just stay the same...

Comment: Can you clean your browser cache and restart your browser to test `http://cloud.mysite.com/` URL.

Comment: Crap. Just noticed I lacked a DNS record for cloud.mysite.com I suppose that would do it... Let me let tha fix to propagate and try again.

Comment: For testing just comment out this line: `#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cloud\.mysite\.com$ [NC]`

Comment: Ok now comment out `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` line as well and test.

Comment: Same problem. No re-write. What is interesting is that I am getting a page that says that no website is configured for this address.

Comment: If your rewrite isn't working without any condition then I suspect browser still doesn't know about `cloud.mysite.com`. You can rename .htaccess to something else and then try to visit this URL in browser `http://cloud.mysite.com/`